# Efficiently searching a list to find specific Instance, without using `equals()` or `hashCode()`

Tags: java, serialization

I'm implementing a simple serialisation mechanism.  Serialising an object recursively trawls its fields and writes them out to a stream.  To avoid endless loops, when it encounters an object to write it checks to see if it's seen it before, if so then it writes a marker instead.  This relies on maintaining a searchable list of objects it's seen before.  The list's `indexOf()` and `contains()` methods can't use `Object.equals`, they must use `==` instead, since an object graph might have two objects in it that are identical in terms of the data, but should not actually be the same object.  If i use a simple `Map<Object, Integer>` with the following example graph, then something bad happens:

```
   root: ParentObject (class Parent)
      field1:  ChildObject1 (class Child)
         data: "Hello"
      field2:  ChildObject2 (class Child)
         data: "Hello"
```

When serialised the `Map` finds `ChildObject1` when asked to see if `ChildObject2` has been written before, because the `.equals()` method returns true.  When deserialised, the object tree now looks like this:

```
   root: ParentObject (class Parent)
      field1:  ChildObject1 (class Child)
         data: "Hello"
      field2:  <reference to ChildObject1>
```

Now the problem is that if something modifies `ChildObject1` then the apparent `ChildObject2` also has that change, which is different behaviour to what would have happened before serialisation.  If these objects were immutable then this would not be a problem, but this mechanism is meant to be general purpose and can't ensure immutability, and in the specific case i actually need it for objects are not immutable either.

In a lower level language i would simply create a lookup based on pointer address, but that's not an option here.

I can use a simple `List<Object>`, and do a linear search on `list.get(i) == needle`, but this is very inefficient.  My first thought is a simple binary search, but what do i search on?  There's no identifying information, no key, to use.  This seems to preclude the use of any more efficient lookup structure.

I have used `Unsafe` in the past to output identity information (basically the object's pointer) for debug logging purposes, but this seems, well, "unsafe"!   In the back of my mind i have this idea that the JVM might be free to move things around, for example after a GC, which would break this approach, too.

How can i work around this problem?

Comment: "The list's indexOf() and contains() methods can't use Object.equals" <- Then why not just override those methods?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS that's kind of the question - how would you rewrite them? in a basic List it's straightforward, but try to apply the same to a Set or Map and you run into problems. Or, at least, i do :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear scan of a list will be `O(N)` where `N` is the list length.  That's not efficient, and you can't make it efficient.

You could use `System.identityHashcode(Object)` to calculate a hashcode that will be compatible with `==`.

But there is a simpler solution.  There is a `Map` class called `IdentityHashMap` which is pretty much designed for your use-case.  This `Map` implementation has `O(1)` lookup and insertion (amortized)